# Dart syntax highlighting is not highlighting dart code

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I have installed dart(Syntax highlighting only) extension but it is not highlighting my dart code.I have restarted my VS code several times after installing extension but couldn't get this to work.
Someone please let me know the issue and how can I resolve this.

Below is my VS code screenshot:

[image: vs]

**THANKS**

Comment: You shouldn't use Dart and Dart(syntax) extensions together, as far as I know. Dart extension already has syntax highlighting and other features.

Comment: @Denis Then how can I get syntax highlighted in dart.

Comment: Delete or disable Dart(syntax) extension

Comment: I just disabled Dart(Syntax highlighting only) plugin and reloaded VS code but there is no change.

Comment: I see you are using Flutter, try to install Flutter extension in addition.

Comment: I think Dart extension works, but it is not supposed to highlight Flutter related stuff

Comment: Yes, I have installed flutter too then too its not working.

Comment: Oh... Sorry, I've run out of ideas(

Comment: Oh :-)....Anyways thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Looking at the picture, your code appears to have some syntax highlighting. Imports, keywords, annotations and string literals are colored. What do you expect the highlighted code to look like?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need the "Syntax highlighting only" extension if you have the Dart one, since the Dart one includes the same syntax highlighting.

Based on your screenshot, it seems like syntax highlighting is working fine - I can see multiple colours. I think the issue is likely the VS Code theme you're using. **Dark (Visual Studio)** only shows limited colours - try changing it to **Dark+** and you should see more colours.

**Dark**

[image: Dark theme]

**Dark+**

[image: Dark+ theme]

---

To Change This Settings;

Setting Icon **>** Color Theme **>** Select **Dark+** Configuration;

[image: Change Theme Settings]

[image: Dark+ Configuration]

Comment: Looks like dark+ is the best of them all.